# Bulma level item height is too small

Tags: css, bulma

How could i make sure my `<p class="title"></p>` and
`<p class="subtitle"></p>` are displayed underneath of eachother because right now they are being displayed next to eachother

Comment: Do you already have some CSS? Could you please share it here? If you write two `p` tags the second already goes in new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `flexbox`, it'll definitely solve your problem.

**Example**

If you want to arrange two items underlying with each other:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="title">Hello</p>
<p class="subtitle">World</p>
</div>
```

If you want to arrange two items next to each other.

```css
.container {
    display: flex; /*by default it will align items in one row*/
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
    <p class="title">Hello</p>
    <p class="subtitle">World</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes , correct way but mistake is in his CSS code because `<p>` tag is a block-level element , so always start from new line

Comment: @Rana yes i agree